# Is XSS possible when using htmlspecialchars and https prefix check in href?

Tags: php, xss, filtering

There is a standard XSS exploitation technique where one can use *javascript* keyword in `<a href="">` to execute javascript code. Example:

```
<a href="javascript:alert(42);">please clickme</a>
```

Let's us consider PHP code which uses `htmlspecialchars` with combination of a prefix check, where the URL must always start with `https://`. Is there any way to exploit it in modern browsers like firefox, chrome?

```
<?php
// PHP 7
$url = htmlspecialchars($_GET["url"] ?? "", ENT_QUOTES);
$text = htmlspecialchars($_GET["text"] ?? "", ENT_QUOTES);
if ((substr($url, 0, 8) !== "https://")) {
    $url = "https://" . $url;
}
?>
<a href="<?= $url; >"><?= $text; ></a>
```

I know that there is a open redirect vulnerability. I tried things like `https://@javascript://://alert();`  but it seems that google chrome blocks it ([medium.com 2017: Say goodbye to URLs with embedded credentials](https://medium.com/@lmakarov/say-goodbye-to-urls-with-embedded-credentials-b051f6c7b6a3)). [This question is not about securing that code - this question is solely about exploiting.]

Here are more examples from the past:

- [youtube, liveoverflow: "HOW FRCKN' HARD IS IT TO UNDERSTAND A URL?! - uXSS CVE-2018-6128"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0uejy9aCNbI&vl=en)
- [youtube, liveoverflow: "Identifying Good Research to actually Learn Something - Cross-site Scripting"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eQFbG6CwwdI)

Comment: probably a browser bug is required to make it exploitable